# Intel C Compiler giving the wrong output when using openmp

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to use the Intel C compiler for the first time and am getting completely the wrong answers.  What am I doing wrong?

I have some code as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 12
#define NUM_THREADS 8

#define popcnt __builtin_popcountll
#define BILLION (1000 * 1000 * 1000)
#define UPDATE_ROW_PPROD() \
    update_row_pprod(row_pprod, row, rows, row_sums, mask, mask_popcnt)

typedef __int128 int128_t;

static inline int64_t update_row_pprod
(
    int64_t* row_pprod, int64_t row, int64_t* rows,
    int64_t* row_sums, int64_t mask, int64_t mask_popcnt
)
{
    int64_t temp = 2 * popcnt(rows[row] & mask) - mask_popcnt;

    row_pprod[0] *= temp;
    temp -= 1;
    row_pprod[1] *= temp;
    temp -= row_sums[row];
    row_pprod[2] *= temp;
    temp += 1;
    row_pprod[3] *= temp;

    return row + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int64_t size = argc - 1, rows[argc - 1];
    int64_t row_sums[argc - 1];
    int128_t permanent = 0, sign = size & 1 ? -1 : 1;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        printf("%d\n", argv[1][0] == '-' ? -1 : 1);
        return 0;
    }

    for (int64_t row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        char positive = argv[row + 1][0] == '+' ? '-' : '+';

        sign *= ',' - positive;
        rows[row] = row_sums[row] = 0;

        for (char* p = &argv[row + 1][1]; *p; p++)
        {
            rows[row] <<= 1;
            rows[row] |= *p == positive;
            row_sums[row] += *p == positive;
        }

        row_sums[row] = 2 * row_sums[row] - size;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:permanent) num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    for (int64_t mask = 1; mask < 1LL << (size - 1); mask += 2)
    {
        int64_t mask_popcnt = popcnt(mask);
        int64_t row = 0;
        int128_t row_prod = 1 - 2 * (mask_popcnt & 1);
        int128_t row_prod_high = -row_prod;
        int128_t row_prod_inv = row_prod;
        int128_t row_prod_inv_high = -row_prod;

        for (int64_t chunk = 0; chunk < size / CHUNK_SIZE; chunk++)
        {
            int64_t row_pprod[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

            for (int64_t i = 0; i < CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
                row = UPDATE_ROW_PPROD();

            row_prod *= row_pprod[0], row_prod_high *= row_pprod[1];
            row_prod_inv *= row_pprod[3], row_prod_inv_high *= row_pprod[2];
        }

        int64_t row_pprod[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

        while (row < size)
            row = UPDATE_ROW_PPROD();

        row_prod *= row_pprod[0], row_prod_high *= row_pprod[1];
        row_prod_inv *= row_pprod[3], row_prod_inv_high *= row_pprod[2];
        permanent += row_prod + row_prod_high + row_prod_inv + row_prod_inv_high;
    }

    permanent *= sign;

    if (permanent < 0)
        printf("-"), permanent *= -1;

    int32_t output[5], print = 0;

    output[0] = permanent % BILLION, permanent /= BILLION;
    output[1] = permanent % BILLION, permanent /= BILLION;
    output[2] = permanent % BILLION, permanent /= BILLION;
    output[3] = permanent % BILLION, permanent /= BILLION;
    output[4] = permanent % BILLION;

    if (output[4])
        printf("%u", output[4]), print = 1;
    if (print)
        printf("%09u", output[3]);
    else if (output[3])
        printf("%u", output[3]), print = 1;
    if (print)
        printf("%09u", output[2]);
    else if (output[2])
        printf("%u", output[2]), print = 1;
    if (print)
        printf("%09u", output[1]);
    else if (output[1])
        printf("%u", output[1]), print = 1;
    if (print)
        printf("%09u\n", output[0]);
    else
        printf("%u\n", output[0]);
}
```

If I compile it with

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -fopenmp  -o permanent permanent.c
```

I can then run it with

```
permanent -+ -+
```

and get the output

```
-2
```

which is correct.

If I instead compile using the Intel C compiler (17.0.1) with

```
icc -std=c99 -qopenmp -Wall permanent.c
```

and then do

```
a.out -+ -+
```

I get

```
11910984139051480114196905982
```

---

As noted in the comments, if you remove the -qopenmp then icc produces a version that runs correctly, albeit only on one core.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I did include a sample input and the correct output. The code computes the permanent of a +-1 matrix.  I am not sure how to get useful info from a debugger for this problem. Any help much appreciated. Maybe I just have the wrong compile flags?

Comment: @eleanora do you get the correct result if you remove `-qopenmp`?

Comment: @davmac Yes! That's a great spot. (It of course now warns "warning #3180: unrecognized OpenMP #pragma" and only runs on one core.)

Comment: @eleanora I don't know much about OpenMP, so I can only suggest then that it's either a bug in Intel's implementation or that your code breaks some restriction that doesn't matter in GCC's implementation. Maybe someone else here on SO will know better.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Sure, there are things to improve, but the original question already contained a complete and verifiable example with compilation instruction, compiler versions, expected vs actual output. That easily makes it into the top10% questions on [openmp].

Comment: Can I install the Intel C compiler on ubuntu ? How can I do it ?

Comment: @alinsoar You can get a trial for free.  Just go to their website or do an Internet search.

Comment: @eleanora thanks. I remember I tried once and I gave up due to unclear instructions for ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Intel's handling of OpenMP reduction on `__int128` type variables. This can be easily reproduced:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    __int128 sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    printf("%" PRIX64 " %" PRIX64 "\n", (uint64_t)sum, (uint64_t)(sum >> 64));
}
```

Output with `-fopenmp`:

> 14000000000 78778300

Correct output without, or with `gcc -fopenmp`:

> 0 0

You can work around that (and keep the `__int128` type) by using a trivial custom reduction declaration:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(add128: int128_t: omp_out = omp_out + omp_in) initializer(omp_priv = 0)
[...]
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(add128:permanent) num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
```

As far as I can tell the standard does not restrict the type of a reduction list element. At least the compiler should tell you if it's not supported.

Comment: Out of interest, is this a known bug? For example, should I report it?

Comment: Please report it and keep the question updated. I can't tell whether it is known or not. At least it seems like a trivial fix for Intel.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the test case, this is definitely a compiler bug in the initialization of the private copy of the reduction variable. You are free to also report the bug, though we will try to file internal bug against appropriate compiler developer.

So, another (not-very-elegant) workaround could be to explicitly initialize the private copy, that is replace

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:permanent) num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
```

with

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:permanent) num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
{
  permanent = 0; // that should be done by compiler actually
  #pragma omp for
  ...
}
```

Comment: If you have a way to file an internal bug report that would be great.